# Ring multiplication in the coincided module

Tags: modules, representation-theory

I'm sorry for any mistakes in the following and for the length, but I tried to be as clear as possible.

**Setup**: Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field and $\Lambda$, $A$ be finite dimensional $K$-algebras (associative and unital). By modules I will mean right modules. Assume that $\phi: \Lambda \rightarrow A$ is a $K$-algebra morphism. I want to understand the coinduced module. That is, if $M$ is a $\Lambda$-module, the coinduced module is the $A$-module defined as follows:

$\bullet$ As a vector space it is $Hom_{\Lambda}(A,M)$. Here we see $A$ as a $\Lambda$-module, with multiplication given by $a\cdot \lambda = a\phi(\lambda)$ for $a\in A$ and $\lambda\in\Lambda$, where the right hand side is the ring multiplication in $A$.

$\bullet$ Multiplication with elements of $A$ in $Hom_{\Lambda}(A,M)$ is given by $[f\cdot a](x) = f(ax)$ for $f\in Hom_{\Lambda}(A,M)$ and $x\in A$. Here $ax$ is just the ring multiplication in $A$.

My problem is in how to compute $f(ax)$. I tried to do it in the following example.

**Example** With the notation above, let $\Lambda$ be given as the path algebra of the quiver
$$ 1 \overset{\alpha_1}{\longrightarrow} 2 \overset{\alpha_2}{\longrightarrow} 3 \overset{\alpha_3}{\longrightarrow} 4$$
and let $A=\Lambda/(\epsilon_1)$, with $\phi: \Lambda \twoheadrightarrow A$ being the natural projection. That is $A$ is the path algebra of
$$ 2 \overset{\alpha_2}{\longrightarrow} 3 \overset{\alpha_3}{\longrightarrow} 4$$
where I keep the same names on the arrows for simplicity. Let $M$ be the following representation of $\Lambda$:
$$M = 0 \overset{0}{\longrightarrow} K \overset{1}{\longrightarrow} K \overset{0}{\longrightarrow} 0.$$
In this step, intuitively, I expect the $A$-module $Hom_{\Lambda}(A, M)$ to be given by the representation
$$K \overset{1}{\longrightarrow} K \overset{0}{\longrightarrow} 0,$$
but I want to check this.

$A$, as an $A$-module, is $A\cong P(2)\oplus P(3)\oplus P(4)$, where $P(i)$ is the indecomposable projective $A$-module corresponding to the vertex $i$. I can see that seeing $A$ as a $\Lambda$-module doesn't change much and $A$ is again the direct sum of $P(2)$, $P(3)$ and $P(4)$ as $\Lambda$-modules. Hence $Hom_{\Lambda}(A,M)$ is two dimensional by a simple computation since $\dim(Hom_{\Lambda}(P(2),M))=\dim(Hom_{\Lambda}(P(3),M)=1$ and $\dim(Hom_{\Lambda}(P(4),M)=0$.

Now I want to check multiplication. Let $f\in Hom_{\Lambda}(P(2),M)$ be given by $f_1=0$, $f_2=1$, $f_3=1$, $f_4=0$ where by $f_i$ I denote the corresponding component of $f$ in the vertex $i$. With this notation, if we see $A$ as a $\Lambda$-module we know precisely where each vector of $A$ is mapped into $M$. Now if $a\in A$ we have $[fa](x) = f(ax)$. So if $x\in A$, where still we see $A$ as a $\Lambda$-module, $x=(0,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ for some $x_2,x_3,x_4\in K$. But then, how can I compute $ax$? If I see $a$ as another element of the form $(0,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ (i.e. in the ''$\Lambda$-module basis'') I do not know how multiplication works. If I see $a$ as a linear combination of paths in $A$ (i.e. in the ''algebra basis'') I have a product of the form $a(0,x_2,x_3,x_4)$, which again I don't know how to compute (since $A$ is a right-module, I would know how to compute $(0,x_2,x_3,x_4)a$, but this is not what I have here). What am I missing here?